# getContentResolver() value null for data but receiving name correctly

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, android-intent-chooser

I'm not able to read data part from the selected image Uri, this happens on some specific device Lg nexus 5 api 6.0.1

*Uri of a selected image*

```
content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content://media/external/images/media/200/ORIGINAL/NONE/2077196451
```

*Code used to get data from the uri*

```
 public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                       String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Not issue with the permissions handling, Required Permissions are given.

Comment: your `Uri` is broken: `content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content://media/external/images/media/200/ORIGINAL/NONE/2077196451` - it should be either `content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/` or `content://media/external/images/media/200/ORIGINAL/NONE/2077196451`

Comment: Getting this exception `Permission Denial: reading com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider.impl.MediaContentProvider uri content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/ from pid=26928, uid=10168 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()`

Comment: using this one `content://media/external/images/media/200/ORIGINAL/NONE/2077196451`

Comment: @pskink `Intent getIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        getIntent.setType("application/pdf");
        Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI).setType("image/*");
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(getIntent, "Select File");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] {pickIntent});
        activity.startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_PICK_FILE);`